# How can I fix my program to where the message zip argument #2 must support iteration does not pop up?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

```
    import random
    from Queue import Queue


    class Deck:
        def __init__(self, decks=1, shuffle=4):
```

Uses a queue system to simulate cards being drawn and discarded
:param decks: number of decks to use
:param shuffle: number of times to shuffle
:return:

```
            self.deck = Queue()
            self.shuffle_times = shuffle
            self.suits = ['spades', 'clubs', 'hearts', 'diamonds']
            self.cards = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K', 'A']
            for deck in range(decks):
                for suit in self.suits:
                    for card in self.cards:
                        self.deck.put([card, suit])

    def draw(self):
```

:return: a random card from the deck

```
        card = self.deck.get()
        return card

    def shuffle(self):
```

Shuffles the deck n times
:return: none

```
        if self.shuffle_times > 0:
            temp = list(self.deck.queue)
            [random.shuffle(temp) for _ in range(self.shuffle_times)]
            self.deck = Queue()
            for card in temp:
                self.deck.put(card)

class Blackjack:
    def __init__(self, decks=1, shuffle=1):
```

:param decks: number of decks to use
:param shuffle: number of times to shuffle
:return: none

```
        self.num_decks = decks
        self.deck = Deck(self.num_decks, shuffle)
        self.deck.shuffle()
        self.cards_dict = {'2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5, '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8,
                       '9': 9, '10': 10, 'J': 10, 'Q': 10, 'K': 10, 'A': 11}
        self.high_low = {'2': 1, '3': 1, '4': 1, '5': 1, '6': 1, '7': 0, '8': 0, '9': 0,
                     '10': -1, 'J': -1, 'Q': -1, 'K': -1, 'A': -1}
        self.games = 0
        self.draws = 0
        self.computer_win = 0
        self.player_win = 0
        self.running_count = 0
        self.player_hand = []
        self.computer_hand = []
        self.player_total = 0
        self.computer_total = 0

    def batlle_bot(self):
```

Uses the Blackjack basic strategy to decide which move to make. Ability to distinguish soft and hard hands

```
        if 'A' in [card[0] for card in self.player_hand]:
            if self.player_total <= 17:
                return 'h'
            elif self.player_total >= 19:
                return 's'
            elif self.player_total == 18 and 2 <= self.computer_total <= 8:
                return 's'
            elif self.player_total == 18 and self.computer_total >= 9:
                return 'h'
        else:
            if self.player_total <= 11:
                return 'h'
            elif self.player_total >= 17:
                return 's'
            elif self.player_total == 12 and 2 <= self.computer_total <= 3:
                return 'h'
            elif 12 <= self.player_total <= 16 and 4 <= self.computer_total <= 6:
                return 's'
            elif 13 <= self.player_total <= 16 and 2 <= self.computer_total <= 3:
                return 's'
            elif 4 <= self.player_total <= 16 and self.computer_total >= 7:
                return 'h'

    def total(self, hand):
    """
    Helper to check for aces in the hand and calculates the value of the hand
    :param hand: list of cards in the hand
    :return: value of the hand
    """
        aces = hand.count(11)
        hand_value = sum(hand)
        if hand_value > 21 and aces > 0:
            while aces > 0 and hand_value > 21:
                hand_value -= 10
                aces -= 1
        return hand_value


    def high_low_count(self, card):
```

Keeps track of the high/low count for card counting
:param card: value of card
:return: value of card according to high/low count

```
        self.running_count += self.high_low[card[0]]
        return card

score = (0, 0, 0, 0)
num_cycles = 1000
num_decks = 6
for i in range(num_cycles):
    game = Blackjack(num_decks).battle_bot=True
    score = tuple([x + y for x, y in zip(score, game)])
    games, draws, player_win, computer_win = score
    print('Player win = {}'.format(player_win))
    print('Computer win = {}'.format(computer_win))
    print('Number of games = {}'.format(games))
    print('Draws = {}'.format(draws))
    try:
        print('Win/Loss = {:.2f}'.format(player_win / computer_win))
    except:
        print('Win/Loss = {}'.format(max(player_win, computer_win)))
    print('\n--------------------\n')
```

The program should print how many times the player wins, the dealer wins, and how many draws.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
game = Blackjack(num_decks).battle_bot=True
score = tuple([x + y for x, y in zip(score, game)])
```

You just assigned `game` and `Blackjack(num_decks).battle_bot` to have the value `True`, then tried to `zip` `score` (a `tuple`, fine) and `game` (a `bool`, not iterable).

I have no idea what you intended here, even if you had called `battle_bot` it would have returned a single letter string, so your `zip` would only produce a single output two-`tuple`, not the four values you seem to think you'll be able to unpack on the very next line (four values with different meanings no less, where the code that produces `scores` seems to treat them equivalently in  ways that wouldn't make sense for the multiple meanings).

You need to consider your program logic, there are far too many logic problems here beyond the small error your posted about.